# Why can't I respond to the responses I've gotten to my question?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Can the mods help me? I'm trying to respond to some of the responses I've gotten in my earlier questions and I just cant do it. I can see other people responding though, I'm just not sure how to do it. I also can't edit my latest question about Worf.

I tried asking this on the "meta" site in the right sidebar but it says I need 5 rep to post there :/

Comment: You need some basic levels of rep to do just about everything except ask questions and answer questions.  Check out the [faq] for more information, particularly [this section](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) and [this section](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/privileges).

Comment: It also appears that you aren't logged in as the same user you asked your other question with. Instead, you seem to have created a new login account. Your other account has 44 reputation, which is almost enough to add comments. Even without enough rep to comment, you can post comments on your own questions or answers, or on answers to your own question. The only reason you can't respond to the responses you received is that you're not logged in with the right account.

Comment: On here I can "Add Comment" - but these problems must have been caused because I registered after asking the questions. is there a way to combine the accounts?

Comment: A moderator can merge your accounts for your. Flag your original question, and ask a moderator to combine them for you.

Comment: @derekvinyard98 If you want your accounts merged, follow Gilles' instructions.

Answer (score 4):

You look like you're signed in a different (though similarly named) account.

The user at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5558/derekvinyard98 has a question and 44 rep. The user posting THIS question is https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5564/derekvinyard98

Did you login with the same credentials?

Comment: That is odd. I had always assumed display names were unique.

Comment: It's not uncommon for display names to be capable of duplication/re-use, particularly in forum-like sites where there's a desire for user-friendliness. Besides, if they were unique, it'd make it difficult to register on one SE site, then use the same profile and credentials on others I think. JMO

Comment: @Xantec - they are not unique. Think "Rondo"

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have accidentally created two accounts: [an unregistered account](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5558/derekvinyard98) (associated with your email) and [a registered account](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5564/derekvinyard98) (associated with your OpenID or other Internet identity).

Please follow the steps mentioned in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist). Specifically, add your OpenID to your [unregistered account](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5558/derekvinyard98) and wait a little. If that doesn't work for some reason, reply here and I'll see what I can do. Moderators can merge accounts, but your unregistered account doesn't have private information that would confirm that you are the same person (and not someone else who chose the same display name).